# Find a sequence of 7 consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find a sequence of 7 consecutive primes, such that these primes have to have the same "gap" in between them. So far I have been doing this in a brute force way, by looking at a list of all the primes and trying different combinations without much luck. Is there a more sophisticated way of doing this?

Comment: Note that the common difference will have to be divisible by $2\times 3\times 5\times 7=210$ in order to avoid divisibility by $2,3,5,7$.

Comment: First, start simple: can you see why a gap of $2$ between primes won't work?  Once you see that, you can ask yourself why a gap of $6=2\cdot 3$ won't work, and by continuing in this approach you should be able to find the minimum gap that you can use.

Comment: You can [look up examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression#Largest_known_consecutive_primes_in_AP).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes i understand why the gap of 2 won't work...oh that helps! I knew there must be a better way to do this, but I just could't figure out the solution. thanks!

Comment: @HenningMakholm exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: And [this usenet post](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/primenumbers/conversations/messages/14831) claims that the smallest known (as of 10 years ago) example is $149143516628800164802930723713131 + 210n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Those may be primes, but they are not _consecutive_ primes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm so thats the smallest example of a consecutive list of 7 primes? I guess my only issue with that is I am trying to check the primality of the numbers in that sequence, but none of the prime calculators I am looking at can support numbers that big

Comment: @MathMajor: Something like Java's BigInteger.isProbablePrime() should handle it with ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://primerecords.dk/cpap.htm lists largest and smallest known examples of consecutive primes in arithmetic progression of a given length.

The *first known* sequence is apparently $19252884016114523644357039386451+210n$, but is not *known to be the first*.

Comment: So for simplicity I just want to pick a small one, but I just want to make sure I am reading the chart correctly, so I look at CPAP-k with a k of 7 right? So I chose: 1205967 · 61# + x32a + 210n but I don't understand what the a and # are symbolizing?

Comment: @MathMajor: $61\#$ is a _primorial_, that is, the product of all primes up to $61$. And $x_{32a}$ is a particular 32-digit number that is listed further down that page. The smallest known CPAP-7 base is quoted explicitly slightly _above_ the "smallest _known_ CPAP-k" table, after the words "The smallest known is 32 digits".

Comment: Oh ok, so primorial is like a factorial, but exclusively for the prime numberS?

Comment: @MathMajor: Yes.